# Probability density function from a set of data

Tags: probability

Given a set of experimental data f={fk} for k=1,2,...,N, how can I find the best pdf which approximate the set fk? In the case of a gaussian distribution, applying the maximum likelihood criteria, it's easy to find the couple (μ,σ), but if I don't know anything about the distribution of the data, is the maximum likelihood estimate still valid? And if the answer is 'yes' what is the formula?

Many thanks.

Comment: Everything hinges on what is meant by "best".  That, in turn, should depend on what use will be made of the estimated PDF.  Will you be testing a scientific theory, predicting a future outcome, using the PDF as input for additional analyses, advising people what action to take?  Do you need to reproduce the mean and variance accurately or perhaps (if you are doing risk assessment or failure analysis) do you need to characterize one of the tails and extrapolate with it?  Without this information, we can only guess what answer may be appropriate.

Comment: Would be good to know the reason for the down vote on this. Seems like a fine question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best arbitrary probability measure is of course a discrete distribution taking values $f_i$ with probability $\frac1N$, but I have a feeling that's not what you want.

If you want something that generalizes well, you need to guess the functional form of some probability measures, fit each of them, and then test your guesses with cross-validation.  It would be nice to know something about how the data is generated to be able to make good guesses.

To answer your direct question, the maximum likelihood normal distribution might not be the distribution that generalizes best with your data.  For example, if your data is actually distributed according to an exponential distribution, then a Gaussian fit will be really bad.

Comment: If you allow me, Neil G, I would just point out that the empirical distribution you describe at the beginning of your answer has no density (pdf). Sorry to nitpick with the terminology, but a student reading this may be confused.

Comment: @Zen: Yes, good point, thank you.  Feel free to edit my answer to improve it.